# installing epson xp-420 printer/scanner

Tags: drivers, printing

I am new to Linux so not truly understanding what I'm doing (but loving it so far!!) I am trying to install my printer which is connected via WIFI but when I install the packages from Epson, I get:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable:lsb (>=3.2)
```

I ran the system updates and no idea where to go.
I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install drivers downloaded from the official website.

1. Go to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX
2. Select your device
3. Select proper driver
4. Download `.deb` file
5. Double click on `.deb` file to install it